# Android - Button in a GridView Clicking Continuously

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gridview

I am having an issue to handle `onClickListener` for a button in `GridView` item. I click the button once. However after executing the `onClick` function once, it is being called automatically for a certain time. How can I prevent the auto clicking the button? Here is my adapter code:

```
@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    assert inflater != null;
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_product,parent,false);

    Button buy = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_buy);
    buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        double price = Double.parseDouble(products.get(position).getProductPrice());
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,
                    "Getting Information ...", "Please wait...", true);

            assert user != null;
            final String userId = user.getUid();

            database.child(userId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        userInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        assert userInfo != null;
                        double coin = Double.parseDouble(userInfo.getUserCoin());

                        if (coin<price){
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Not enough Coin.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            coin -= Double.parseDouble(products.get(position).getProductPrice());
                            userInfo.setUserCoin(String.valueOf(coin));
                            database.child(userId).setValue(userInfo).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()){

                                        Operation.ShowAlertDialogue(context);

                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error. Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Something not right.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

The code inside `OnClick` method keeps executing until the `coin` value becomes 0. How can i prevent it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the exact behaviour the way you coded the `onClick` execution on your `buy` button. You have added `addValueEventListener` on the specific user id node of your Firebase database and then you are setting `database.child(userId).setValue(userInfo)` again inside the `onDataChange` method. This is triggering the `addValueEventListener` to be called again as this is the exact behaviour of this overridden function. `addValueEventListener` will be [called each time the data is changed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events) in your Firebase database on that exact node where you are keeping your reference to.

To overcome this problem, I would suggest you use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` instead of `addValueEventListener` which will be called once for fetching the values from your Firebase database. You might consider taking a look at the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once) as well.

I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Reaz it solved the issue. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Great to know that I could help. Glad to see a developer from Bangladesh in Stackoverflow. You are welcome. :)